# how can I render a quarto website to a single pdf

Tags: r, quarto

I have a quarto website that I was asked to render to PDF.

```
quarto render .
```

will produce all the necessary HTML content on the `_site` directory. I can also run

```
quarto render . --to pdf
```

which works, but produces many PDF files corresponding the the HTML files in of the previous command.

Is there a way, without drastically changing my `_quarto.yml` file (this is a one-time operation, the website is still the primary output), to render a *single* PDF, where all the pages are merged into one long document?

The `--merged` part of what follows doesn't actually exist, but I'm thinking something like:

```
quarto render . --to pdf --toc --merged
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [this post](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/5782) it is not possible, but there is a workaround that fits some use cases (is you use the "book" subtype of "website".

I have asked a [similar question](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/6636) on the discussion boards for Quarto, there might be answers of interest there if it gets any traction.